# Sphinx - loading pickled environment... failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: pickle, python-sphinx

When I'm generating the documentation I got the following error:

```
loading pickled environment... failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/project/.doctrees/environment.pickle'
```

The thing is that file do exists:

```
[me@server project]$ ls -al /home/me/project/.doctrees/environment.pickle
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me group 723522 Feb 28 15:52 /home/me/project/.doctrees/environment.pickle
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible you created the previous pickled environment with another version of Python?  The 'no file or directory' error could be masking a problem with reading the pickle file...I would delete the whole build directory and run a fresh one, assuming you haven't already

Comment: I tried deleting the whole build directory but it didn't help :(